# How to set LSTM for train on multiple time series on keras?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, keras, time-series, lstm

Greeting, everyone! I have $X = (x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$, and $Y = (y_1,y_2,...,y_n)$ where $x_i$ - is a time series, and $y_i$ - is the output time series for $x_i$. e.g. for $x_{ik}$ *($i$ - index of time series, $i = 1,n$, $k$ - number of pattern(idk how it's named), $k=1,t$, $t$ - size of $x_i$)*, I have $y_{ik}$, I'll pray that you understand me))

What I want to do: I want to train LSTM-based NN, for predicting $X$ to $Y$. As you seen, for each $x_ik$, I have $y_ik$, so I think that it will be great, if NN will learn on whole time series, not just on the last point, question is how I should set my NN in **Keras**?

For the end, once again, I try to explain:
$x_i = (x_{i1}, x_{i2},...,x_{ik})$ and output is $y_i = (y_{i1}, y_{i2},...,y_{ik})$, but for now I train my model with $x_i = (x_{i1}, x_{i2},...,x_{ik})$ and $y_i = y_{ik}$ - so it's just one last point.